# Why undefined plus undefined equals to Nan in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined, nul

How to understand undefined and null much better

```js
console.log(undefined + 5) //NaN

console.log(null + 5) //5

console.log(undefined + undefined) //NaN
```

Comment: first one should give `NaN` rather than `null`

Comment: Check this https://javascript.info/types

Comment: @NickParsons. I got something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-prftcs)

Comment: @Idon'tknow stackblitz shows `null` even when you `console.log(NaN)`, it seems like it shows `null` when it really should be showing `NaN` (see your browser console instead for more accurate results).

Comment: @NickParsons yes It gives `NaN`. My entire question goes wrong. because of stackblitz.. Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` operator applies an implicit coercion to an integer to an operand when the other is a number

`undefined` is coerced to `NaN`, so `console.log(undefined + 5)` and `console.log(undefined + undefined)` output `NaN`

`null` is coerced to number `0`, so `console.log(null + 5)` is equivalent to `console.log(0 + 5)`. Therefore 5 is outputted

Comment: Specified in section [9.3 ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)